# Are there any benefits for eliminating Exalt forces on Covert Extraction?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

One of the Covert Operations missions is [Covert Extraction](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Covert_Extraction). The third and final objective, once you get your operative to safety, is as follows:

> Eliminate the remaining EXALT forces, or get to the EVAC zone.

Are there any benefits to killing the EXALT forces instead of just fleeing?

Comment: It's quite a long time ago since I played it, so I am not certain enough to I post it as a real answer. But I THINK you get to loot their guns if you choose to eliminate them while you don't get any EXALT equipment if you evac.

Comment: Plus XP gains for each solider that gets a kill.  The EXALT extration missions I found to be a fairly easy gain of XP, set up covering fire and just wait for them to charge in.

Comment: I routinely evac'd these missions rather than fight it out and I never noticed *a loss* from it, even when playing Long War.  I'm sure there are some benefits (as discussed above) but I'm not convinced it's *worthwhile*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on where your forces are, it can be easier and faster to just kill the rest of them. They also drop whatever weapon they're using, and the soldier who kills them will get XP from it.

Other than that, feel free to GTFO in the Skyranger, since your operative has all the intel that the local government will need to destroy the cell on their own.

Comment: Are weapons recovered if you evacuate? Or only if you kill them all? I'm guessing that XP gets awarded either way.